# Distance between two points in different sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am working on the following problem:

[image]

This is a sketch of the proof:

Let x e B, and let x be s.t x = max(B), thus x > x'', for all x'' e B. Also let some x' e A s.t x' = min A. Now let d(x,x')=0 but this implies that x e A, hence B is a subset of A.

Now, suppose by contradiction, that B is a subset of A and exist some x e B, s.t x = max(B) and max(x e B)min(x' e A) d(x,x') > 0. But then x does not belong to A, which contradicts the initial assumption.

I think it is on the right track but rather incomplete and I cannot figure out what I am missing. Do I use the max(x e B) min( x e A) d(x,x') = 0 statement properly? Any hints or remarks are very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ doesn't have an ordering. How do you mean $\sup(B)$?

Comment: Oh, yes you are totally right. I totally forgot it is not R- I will edit it now.

Comment: I will assume that by saying $x$ is maximum, you mean with respect to some norm. But then you can't just 'let' the distance be zero. The distance is something that is already defined and fixed, and not necessarily zero. On another note, please look into MathJax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we consider the quantity

$$d'(A,B):= \max_{x \in B}\left(\min_{x' \in A} d(x,x')\right) \tag{1}$$

which is well defined as the function $d: X \to X$ is continuous to $\Bbb R$ and so assumes all maxima and minima on compact sets $A$ and $B$.

So assume $B \subseteq A$ first. Then for any fixed $b \in B$ we know that $b \in A$ too, so we can take $x=b, x'=b$ in the formula for $d'(A,B)$ and note that $\min_{x' \in A} d(b,x') = 0$ and the maximum we're taking of all these minima (over *all* posssible $b \in B$) is just a maximum of a set consisting only of $\{0\}$.
It follows that $d'(A,B)=0$.

We can use a contrapositive for the other direction. If $B \nsubseteq A$ there is **some** fixed $b \in  B$ such that $b \notin A$.
Well, for that fixed $b$ we already know that $\min_{x' \in A} d(x', b) = d(b,A) >0$ (because e.g. $d(b,A)=0$ iff $b \in \overline{A}$ in any metric space, and $A$ is closed and $b \notin A$) and so the maximum of all these, $d'(A,B) \ge d(b,A) >0$ as well.

This shows the equivalence in what I think is the simplest way.

Comment: Note that one way to define the Hausdorff distance between $A$ and $B$ is $\max(d’(A,B), d’(B,A))$. This fact then shows one axion for that metric.